# connect a web application with Google Cloud Platform

Tags: web, google-cloud-platform

I'm working on a project in which I've to create a web app for image processing and connecting it with a virtual machine (created using "app engine" of Google Cloud platform) so that the image processing can be done with a python code installed in this virtual machine. I've already the python code working on the virtual machine i've just to create the web app. I'm new in this field can you help me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that SO is not a coding service, you need to show your efforts. Please also take the time to go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking. Thanks.

Comment: i'm not asking for a code , i don't know how to do the link between GCP and my web app so that i can run the python code (for image processing) present in the VM on the web app. i think you didn't understand my question

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you have a look at some of the tutorials that Google have for building applications in App Engine.

The following tutorial is for building one in Python:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/creating-guestbook

As for image processing, I would suggest using the [Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/). A quickstart tutorial can be found here:
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart